# How to see caret when big ENTER pressed in InputField in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field, unity-ui

I have a strange behaviour when using original InputField. My problem is next. I have 2 ENTER button on keyboard. The first is BIG ENTER(1), the second NUM PAD ENTER(2).
[image]
I place original unity InputField( or InputField Text Mesh Pro the same behaviour) to UI. When i press BIG ENTER caret dissapear and i have to push left mouse button to handle next line.
[image]
How to set to BIG ENTER the same behaviour in InputField like NUM PAD ENTER ?

Answer (score 0):

Understand that focus removed help me to understand, found it when make a picture in Photoshop. Removing this code solved this problem. GL&HF

```
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)
```